# implications of convergence in sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

If we are given that $O \subset \Omega$ is open and bounded and $a: \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We have a sequence $\{u_{m}\}$ satisfying $$ u_{m} \rightharpoonup u\text{   } \text{   in    }\text{    } W^{1,\infty}_{0}(O)$$ and

$$\limsup\limits_{m \rightarrow \infty}\int_{O} \langle a(x,u_{m}, \nabla u_{m}); \nabla(u_{m}-u)\rangle dx \leq 0$$ where $\langle \text{  } \rangle$ is the scalar product.

How does this imply the following two conditions to $u_{m} \rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,\infty}(O)$ and $\Vert \nabla u_{m} \Vert_{L^{\infty}(O)} \leq \sigma$ where $\sigma > 0$.

Please view this pdf link [Research Paper Question Refers To](http://caa.epfl.ch/publications/9-Boccardo-Dacorogna1984.pdf). The  above question refers to how we can use Lemma 1 at the start of the proof of Lemma 2.

Let me know if my question is still unclear. Thanks.

Comment: What is $p$ and what are the conditions imposed in $a$? Also, is $u_m$ some particular sequence? With this generality, the result you want is not true.

Comment: Hi Tomas please view changes to question. I have added a hyperlink to pdf in question. This is the document that I am studying. To answer your question $a$ is taken as a Caratheordory function with $|a(x,s,\xi)| \leq k(x) = \beta(|s|^{p-1} + |\xi|^{p-1})$ for almost every $x \in \Omega$, for every $(x, \xi) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and for some $k \in L^{p^{'}}(\Omega)$, $\beta \geq 0$, $p > 1$.

Comment: Is there any possibility of taking this discussion to chat to discuss some points regarding this paper?

Comment: Do you have Skype? My native language is not English, but I think I can talk something.

Comment: Hi Tomas, I unfortunately don't have access to a pc with Skype at the moment. I make use of campus computers(which is why my responses might me delayed at times). Have you had a chance to look at the paper? My email is dlucio50@yahoo.com, I can check this more regularly than the forum. If possible maybe we could discuss some points on the forum chat or facebook chat? Thanks for you responses, much appreciated.

Comment: Dear Lucio, I can't see the relation of your question with the paper. Could you be more specific please? Thank you

Comment: Hi Tomas. It says at the start of the proof of Lemma 2 "Proof: Let $\{u_{m}\}$ be as in (2.13) and (2.14). Then Lemma 1 implies that we can find $v_{m}$ such that $v_{m} \rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,\infty}(O)$." But in order to apply Lemma 1 we need conditions (2.1) and (2.2) to be satisfied. I want to know how (2.13) and (2.13) implies these conditions, which are necessary to use Lemma 1.

Comment: In my copy of the paper, condition (2.13) is weak star convergence in $W_0^{1,\infty}(O)$, not in $W_0^{1,p}(O)$ as you have stated in your question. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, weak convergence in $W^{1, \infty}_{o}(O)$ is correct.

Comment: Do you know that weak star convergence implies boundedness?

Comment: Yes I see. So does it simply follow from $||Du_{m}||_{L^{1,\infty}} \leq ||u_{m}||_{W^{1,\infty}} \leq M$ for some fixed $M > 0$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Seems strange to state (2.2) as a separate condition if it is implied by (2.1). Could I ask two more questions about the paper?

Comment: Indeed, it seem strange. Maybe he stated (2.2) just to avoid the trivial case where $u_m=0$ for all $m$. Please, let me hear the other questions.

Comment: Firstly, I am studying Sobolev spaces independently, haven't taken any courses, so this might be trivial. Out of interest I would like to know if we can take (2.16) further and state that $v_{m} \rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,\infty}_{o}(O)$ as well. I also don't see how (2.19) follows?

Comment: Why would $u=0$?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem. You are right with respect to the first question. The convergence can be viewed also in $W_0^{1,\infty}(O)$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13493/discussion-between-lucio-d-and-tomas)